# WEP password cracking

Tags: network, wifi, password-cracking, wep

I was testing WEP password cracking on my router. I had set a thirteen character password ("TESTING123456") and tried these commands:

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

Then I started airodump-ng using this command:

```
airodump-ng mon0
```

After this I performed "fake authentication" using:

```
aireplay-ng -1 3 –a 98:fc:11:c9:14:22 mon0
```

Then I executed these commands:

```
airodump-ng mon0 --bssid 98:fc:11:c9:14:22 --channel 6 --write RHAWEP

aireplay-ng -3 –b 98:fc:11:c9:14:22 –h 00:c0:ca:50:f8:32 mon0
```

The problem is that the IV (Initialization vectors) are coming very slowly. I 
have collected 428000 beacon packets and only received 27000 IVs. I saw some tutorials where the ratio of beacon packet vs IV was about 2:1.

So is there any other way to grab IVs faster ? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

EDIT:----

Is there any other method to crack a WEP password? If there are, please suggest some other methods.

Comment: Not all wireless adapters support injection; use this test to make sure yours does: http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=injection_test&DokuWiki=7a9c7f1d9e6c48b9f2d175e52de665f8

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of any other methods to crack WEP as this is probably the fastest way and a technique you can be sure will end up giving you the key.

That said, you may want to check that command

```
aireplay-ng -3 –b 98:fc:11:c9:14:22 –h 00:c0:ca:50:f8:32 mon0
```

The second mac in there is supposed to belong to a client already authenticated on the AP when you start the capture, this should not be any random one.

Other than that, as said in the comments, only thing I can see is your wireless card is badly configured, you have the wrong drivers, or it is simply not supported (which the card you seem to have should be).

If everything goes right you should get IV's very quick. With a bad wireless card i manage to get approximatively 10K each 3-5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old thread but I feel still relevant especially for new comers like myself who are starting out learning to crack WEP.

I have exactly the same problem and I am using a similar wifi card (AWUS036NHA).
Until I get another manufacturer such as Panda I won't know if this is a problem with the ALFA cards.

NB: If the target AP has a an active client communicating, I don't have any issue but if the target AP is quite and I need to do packet injection to generate IV's, I have the issue.

When running **arpreplay** I would get some ACK's but 0 ARP requests and 0 packets sent.

```
aireplay-ng -3 -b [BSSID-MAC] -h [CARD-MAC] wlan0mon
```

[image: arreplay issue]

I found running a deauth on my card while running arpreplay triggered the arpreplay attack to start sending packets.

```
aireplay-ng -0 5 -a <BSSID-MAC> -c <CARD-MAC> wlan0mon
```

[image: arreplay issue resolved]
.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. You don't answer OP's question and just state that you have the same problem, and then give details about that problem.

Comment: If you read my response properly I gave a solution using a deauth to trigger IV’s to be generated. I shall update to remove my further issue.